# New Version of my Android App crashes due to malformed xml, inflater fails to inflate textview, but xmlns:android is defined

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I've developed a Time Clock application for a device running 4.1.1, my debug version was working on the device while testing.

I made some modifications adding 1 textview and a custom toast view which included and imageview and textview.

When I install the app on the device, it launches and crashes throwing this error:

```
04-21 17:53:17.623 4542-4542/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zebra.ar05.ztimeclock/com.zebra.ar05.ztimeclock.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class TextView
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class TextView
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                 at com.zebra.ar05.ztimeclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5081)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getResourcePackageName(ResourcesWrapper.java:254)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.initializeRedirectionMap(Resources.java:2320)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:193)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:171)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.<init>(ResourcesWrapper.java:46)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.<init>(TintResources.java:34)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.<init>(TintContextWrapper.java:100)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.wrap(TintContextWrapper.java:68)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                 at com.zebra.ar05.ztimeclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5081) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Alright found the actual stacktrace my problem is coming from my date textview element here is the xml for that:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="100sp"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:text="DATE"/>
```

The output of an XML validator is:

```
The prefix "android" for attribute "android:id" associated with an element type "TextView" is not bound.
```

Literally mind blown right now... Where do I go from here?

I've got the latest support library: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.zebra.ar05.ztimeclock.MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="150sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="80sp"
    android:minHeight="100sp"
    android:minWidth="100sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

App runs fine when textview is removed from main layout. Still crashes loading either ImageView or Textview in custom toast... Functions fine in emulator running same OS version. Could this be caused by the custom version of 4.1.1?

Comment: That error is not coming from your process. If your app is crashing, you are looking for a Java stack trace coming from your process. BTW, please post stack traces as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @CommonsWare posted the correct stack trace as text, apologies. Why would my android namespace not be bound for this element specifically it seems to load the `DigitalClock` element just fine.. which i'm pretty sure inherits `TextView`

Comment: That's the right stack trace. However, I have no idea why you would be getting that crash. Make sure that you are on the latest version of the Android Support Library artifacts (presently 25.3.1). With regards to your XML validator, that message indicates that you do not have `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` on the root element of your layout resource.

Comment: "at com.zebra.ar05.ztimeclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)" What is line 44 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` I may have found a solution I'll update after I try it

Comment: Ugghhh the fix i thought would work didn't, but it may have set me on the right path. Thanks all for the help! [Fix That Didn't Work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541722/inflate-exception-error-inflating-textview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by Removing AppCompatActivity from my main activiy `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` and changed it to `MainActivity extends Activity`

and also removing the `compile:android.appcompat.v7` reference from my gradle.build file. Apparently the AppCompat libraries weren't supported on the device I was deploying on. What led me to discover this was actually in the stack trace but buried deep.

```
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getResourcePackageName(ResourcesWrapper.java:254)
                                             at android.content.res.Resources.initializeRedirectionMap(Resources.java:2320)
                                             at android.content.res.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:193)
                                             at android.content.res.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:171)
                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.<init>(ResourcesWrapper.java:46)
                                             at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.<init>(TintResources.java:34)
                                             at android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.<init>(TintContextWrapper.java:100)
                                             at android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.wrap(TintContextWrapper.java:68)
                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                             at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                             at com.zebra.ar05.ztimeclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44) 
                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5081) 
                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

A `NullPointerException` was thrown by `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` that's when I realized I wasn't actually calling the `TextView` class in my `activity_main.xml` layout file, because I was using the `android.support.v7` library I was actually calling a `AppCompatTextView` which wasn't support on the device. At least it appears to be this way.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you are trying to use a parameter in the "time" column that has already saved or used in your database because, it´s a constraint that you put in your database

Comment: I use sql server backend my code doesn't interact with SQLite at all. Updated my stacktrace and found my real error.